# Android: Is it is possible to override the default dialog title and set our own xml

Tags: android

I want to override default setTitle method of Dialog class.
We can have only text there. But i want to have text and image as a part of title.

I have one text and image in one xml. Which i want to set it as title.
How can i do this. Please guide me. If any sample code is provided it will be great help.
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can override it

```
@Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence aTitleText) 
    {   
        TextView tilteView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.title);
        tilteView.setText(aTitleText);      
    }
```

& before setting any content view to dialog use

```
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Comment: `R.id.title` is the TextView which serv as Title for your dialog which is defined in your dialog layout

Comment: Satya, i need image which resides besides the Text view. I have an xml for this. How do we set custom rowlist for list view. Similarly i want to set my custom title dialog. Which has image and textview

Answer (score 0):

You should build a custom dialog in order to have the layout you want.

You can find more here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog

Hope this helps!

Comment: I think question is about to display dialog with custom Title bar with image and text.

Comment: Yes i want to have a title bar which has image and text. I saw the link. But there we can have custom body of dialog. I did not got any clue to custom the title of dialog

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/icon"></ImageView>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/title" android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" android:text="Title"
            android:gravity="center" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView android:id="@+id/list" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

`   for listview use your custom (ArrayAdapter)adapter & in getview method of adapter return your row view

Comment: Hi satya. Sorry i guess you did not get my question. Please visit this link http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog Can you see the title custom dialog its plain text there. Where i have to replace it by image followed by text.So how do i go about this.

Comment: thats the default title of window so you can not change it for this 1 option is to disable windows title by requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); in dialog constructor & then in dialog layout set top header view with image & text

Comment: Yeah this is possible. Thank you satya for suggestion